# Adding a project to Tomcat's classpath in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, I add a Tomcat Server. I click on *Open launch configuration*, and in the **Edit Configuration** dialog, tab **Classpath** I can add an Eclipse project to the "User Entries" classpath.

Now I want to achieve the same in IntelliJ Idea. This project has properties files (configuration files) that are shared by many WAR servlets.

What I've tried so far:

In IDEA the servers are configured under the **Application Servers** dialog. There I see Tomcat's jars under *Libraries* and you can *Attach Files or Directories*. I've tried that to add my properties folder inside the project. I've also packaged the project to a JAR (I'm using Maven) and added that archive. Sadly I haven't had any success.

Comment: P:S. I'm using Intellij 12 (public preview, but it's going to be released in a few weeks) and Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed tutorial
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat

Also, the Idea help page might prove useful
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the configuration and properties file/folders in the generated deployment artifact (war / exploded war) for your application. These files/folders will be removed when the deploy able artifact is cleaned.
But it would be nice to have an automatic way of doing this by using the intellij IDE only.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I have not been able to solve it in a way similar to how Eclipse does it, but I did find a solution.

The only solution that I have found is to include a reference to the project/resources in your pom file. This can include a resources tag inside the build tag.

```
<build>
...
<resources>
    <resource>                    
        <directory>path/to/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

If you need the resources for testing then you can do the following:

```
... 
<build> 
    <plugins> 
        <plugin> 
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.9</version> 
            <configuration> 
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/jar</additionalClasspathElement> 
                </additionalClasspathElements> 
            </configuration> 
        </plugin> 
    </plugins> 
</build> 
...
```

The problem that I see with this solution is that I have to add a path to the resources and commit that change in the pom. Any other developer that might have these resources in a separate folder will have to change the pom to point to the location of their resources.

By the way, I got some of this solution from the following conversation.

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/How-to-add-a-folder-to-the-classpath-used-during-maven-build-td4754387.html